# Postfix on Linux: easy way of masquerade_exceptions=<all system users>?

Tags: postfix, masquerade

... well, the subject says it: in a **NULLCLIENT** configuration, we want to have all *normal  users* to be `masqueraded`, but all *system users* should be exposed.

The sysadmins get system user's mails from a lot of different hosts, and want to see eg. `lp@hostname.example.net`, instead of `lp@example.net`, not knowing which host has printing issues.

We could script it to get all users < 1000 from /etc/passwd and filling `masquerade_exceptions=` accordingly, but perhaps there is a more convenient way provided by postfix itself...?

Comment: How do you differentiate system and normal user? Based on which conditions?

Comment: ... as said: for example, by UID<1000 or--if you use NIS/LDAP--all users in /etc/passwd, because "real users" would then come from NIS/LDAP, and the local /etc/passwd would contain only system users.

Comment: Why cant you use `masquerade_exceptions = proxy:unix:passwd.byname` ?